# segmentation fault setting private data

Tags: c++

I have a 7 x 7 matrix of probes that deliver a signal representing the level measured at that point in the area under investigation.  Each element of the matrix is a cpp (g++) class and I get segmentation fault when I try to set private data element rect.x an element of SDL_Rect to a value.

```
class Probe
{
public:
    Probe();
    ~Probe();
    void SetColor(int x);
    void Set_id(int x, int y, int z);
    void Level_id(void);

private:
    int OldColor;
    int Xcord;
    int Ycord;
    SDL_Rect rect;
};
//When I access rec using the public functions, rect.x returns 0 
//and setting it to a value give a segment fault at run time.
//ie.
rect.x = Xcord; //segment fault
foo = rect.x; // returns 0, the starting value I suppose.
//My workround is to create a rect locally in each public function 
SDL_Rect rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
//and it is like I think it should be.  So I'm not stuck.  Ian
//More details
//#include etc
Probe Level[7][7]; //49 instances of the class
void Probe::Set_id(int x, int y, int z)
    {
    Xcord = x;
//Segment fault
    Ycord = y;
    OldColor = z;
//  Defininlg rectangles
    SDL_Rect rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
//  rect.x = BLOCK_W * Xcord; //Segment fault
//  rect.y = BLOCK_H * Ycord;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( ren, OldColor, 0, 0, 255 );
    SDL_RenderFillRect( ren, &rect );
//  if (0 != SDL_FillRect(surface, &rect, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, OldColor, 0, 0)));
//      { std::cout << "SDL_FillRect failed in Set_id" << std::endl; }
    }
   void SDL_init()
{
int x, y, z;
z = 10;
    for(y = 0; y <= 7; ++y)
    {
    for(x = 0; x <= 7; ++x)
        {
        z += 25;
        Level[x][y].Set_id(x, y, z);
        }
    }


    for(y = 0; y < 7; ++y)
    {
        for(x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
        { Level[x][y].Level_id(); }
    }
} 
    void MouthPad() {
std::cout << "In MouthPad" << std::endl;
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() )
    { printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" ); }
    else
    {
        SDL_init(); //Get the class going.

        //Main loop flag
        bool quit = false;


        //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;
//etc I hope this helps.  Ian.
```

Comment: You don't show what method your code is being called from.  Perhaps the method is being called on a NULL (or otherwise invalid) pointer?  Putting a printf("%p\n",this); into your method (just before the site of the crash) might indicate if that is the case... if it is, then any read or write of a local member variable will likely cause a segfault, since it dereferences the bad this-pointer.

Comment: You should show SDL_Rect class and its methods.

Comment: Show us a complete example. We can't see what `rect` is and how it's declared in the code that fails.

Comment: Perhaps try your constant with addition, not multiplication. Have you tried GDB and backtrace?